# Не выводит все записи с базы mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой код на php вывода записей из MYSQL с условием:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM genres_posts WHERE game_id = '61' limit 10");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'ekshen') {echo '<li>Экшен<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'simulyator') {echo '<li>Симулятор<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'strategiya') {echo '<li>Стратегия<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'sport') {echo '<li>Спорт<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'priklyuchenie') {echo '<li>Приключение<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'rolevaya-igra') {echo '<li>Ролевая игра<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'golovolomka') {echo '<li>Головоломка<li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'indi') {echo '<li>Инди<li>';}
}
```

Выводится только 1 запись, хотя у этой записи в базе 3 значения, вот при запросе в phpmyadmin выводит все как нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему у меня не выводит все 3 записи на php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь, чтобы в поле url_genre_name заносились значения без пробелов вначале или в конце, бывает такой косяк.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что некорректно написаны теги. Нет закрывающих тегов, везде только открывающие. Возможно где-то из-за поломанной разметки они просто в другом месте отображаются

Comment: Поправил закрывающие теги у LI и все равно также